# How to manipulate the built in metadata of a Qt plugin?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtplugin

Since Qt5 plugins have metadata. I wrote a plugin (cmake) and want to read the metadata from the main app. The results are below:

```
keys: ("IID", "MetaData", "className", "debug", "version")
IID: "org.manuelschneid3r.albert.plugininterface"
className: "AppLauncher"
debug: ""
version: ""
```

How can I influence the debug and version data? Versioning seems to be made in the .pro file. I use cmake and set the minor and major version numbers.
The [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/397/657/view) is quite close-mouthed.